# DOM hierarchy between <td> and <th> tags in html <table>

Tags: html, dom, html-table

I wanted to know if the `<td>` and `<th>` tags in the HTML tags have the same hierarchy or if `<th>` tag has a greater hierarchy than `<td>` tag?

Comment: What do you mean by "hierarchy"? Aside from parent-child relationship, there is no concept of hierarchy in HTML.

Comment: Hierarchy in the DOM, while converting the table into DOM structure

Comment: Then no. `<td>` and `<th>` are "siblings" in the DOM tree. The common parent of both is `<tr>`.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>` and `<th>` are two kinds of table cells, they are "siblings" in a sense that the parent of both of which is generally a `<tr>`. One cannot be a direct child of the other.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>` and `<th>` are both "sisters" with the common parent `<tr>`.

However, `<th>` is usually associated with header cells while `<td>` is frequently associated with standard cells [[1](http://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_th.asp)]. So, it is a good idea to start with `<th>` first, not as a hierarchy but as a cell order.